# My dashboard widgets are “inactive” since Lion upgrade

Tags: macos, dashboard, widgets

Since my upgrade from Snow Leopard to Lion, my dashboard widgets are inactive. I can enter the dashboard, move widgets around, add and remove them, but their content is not updated and I cannot interact with them (they do not respond to mouse clicks in their normal fashion).

I have looked through the Console, but there are no warnings there about the dashboard. How can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up deleting all `com.apple.*dashboard*` files in `$HOME/Library`, and then rebooting. That did the trick.